# View download progress button not working in Get Windows 10 app

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-10-upgrade

The button "View download progress" in Get Windows 10 app is not working!
I want to see the progress but when I click that button it closes the Get Windows 10 app!
I am using Windows 8.1
How can i fix this problem ?
Thank-you

Comment: If it isn't working then it still pending.  You just have to wait until its ready to be downloaded

Answer (score 0):

There are two probable reasons as to why that button is not working

- Change your settings to automatically update Windows
- Download and update *all* your Windows Updates, including optional ones.
- The button will work normally and when you will click to check progress, it will open Windows Update and download Windows 10.